# How to show hidden div after liking facebook page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a website (similar to adf.ly) that shortn urls , but i want to customize my redirection page so that the users must like a facebook page to be redirected to their link .
**Any idea how can I do that ?**

 
This is the div I want to hide and reveal after liking the page :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<a href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/?r=<?php echo base64_encode($url->url) ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block redirect" rel="nofollow"><?php echo e("Redirect me"); ?></a>
</div>
```

I tried so many solutions but I couldn't manage to do what I want :'(

I didn't add the like button yet !
Here's the redirection page if you want to take a look : http://premiumshortener.url.ph/DHpO8

Answer (score 1):

well there is a facebook redirect-link at least when you get the user to "connect"/"accept" your app. Not sure if this is possible with the like page. But you should be able to use the graph api and javascript to ask if the user is a fan/liked a certain page. Based on the result, you could show the div or not.

but some advice from someone beeing in charge of a 6Mio UC/month <-> 1000mio impr/month site; your linkshortener sounds like something someone would use when sharing NSFW/Filesharing links. Thus, people will be in incognito mode (no Facebook) and if they aren't, they will not be okey with liking a page during a link-jump process that can identify them+the url they wanted to look at. Noway someone would accept that. Even for hello-kitty images this is a tuffy... and don't forget; not everybody has a facebook account.

Comment: Thanks first for taking the time to answer my question , do you have any idea how can I manage to do what you said in the first paragraph.
And the website isn't really a website it's just an app I'm developing.

Comment: what would be the first place to look when you develop something that attaches to facebook? Exactly, developers.facebook.com :) All JS-APIs, Graph-API etc. explained